# Partizip 2 als Attribut bei passiv-unfähigen Verben

Tags: passive, past-participle

Wenn man beispielsweise die passiv-unfähigen Verben "stattfinden" oder "passieren" als Partizipialattribute verwenden möchte, gehören folgende Konstruktionen zur Standardsprache oder sind solche Konstruktionen grammatikalisch schlechthin unmöglich?

> Ein Unfall hat stattgefunden -> Der stattgefunden habende Unfall hat uns erschreckt.
>
> Ein Unfall ist passiert -> Der passiert habende Unfall hat uns erschreckt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In solchen Fällen darf man das Hilfsverb einfach weglassen, das Partizip steht dann alleine da (im Prinzip als Adjektiv):

> Ein Unfall hat stattgefunden -> Der stattgefundene Unfall hat uns erschreckt.
>
> Ein Unfall ist passiert -> Der passierte Unfall hat uns erschreckt.

Ob das guter Stil ist oder nicht, kann man diskutieren - Es hört sich für mich ziemlich nach "Amtsdeutsch" an.

Das "hölzerne" klingt ein kleines bißchen mehr akzeptabel, (aber immer noch "amtsdeutsch") wenn man ein Adverbial einfügt:

> Der am 22.5. stattgefundene Unfall ...

Ich persönlich würde so eine Konstruktion deswegen komplett vermeiden und z.B. auf einen Relativsatz ausweichen:

> Der Unfall, der am 22..5 stattgefunden hat, ...

Comment: Die bessere Alternative ist in diesem Fall natürlich das Verb *geschehen*.

Comment: Und bei *passiert* muss ich sofort an die armen Tomaten denken – das ist aber ein anderes (ebenfalls passivunfähiges) *passieren*.

Comment: @Janka Komisch, auf einer Website habe ich folgende Information gelesen:

"stattfinden" ist ein intransitives und nicht passivfähiges Verb, darum kann damit auch keine Partizipialkonstruktion mit dem Partizip II "stattgefunden" gebildet werden.

Auch die Verbindung "stattgefunden habende" ist jämmerlich hölzern und sollte vermieden werden.

Hier empfiehlt sich wirklich Alexanders Tipp: Relativsatz!"

Quelle: https://www.wer-weiss-was.de/t/stattgefundene/2687403/6

Comment: War @tofro gemeint?

Comment: Da ich gefragt wurde: Es klingt hölzern, aber nicht unbedingt falsch. Nicht wie ein Grammatikfehler, sondern so als hätte man ein nicht ganz passendes Verb verwendet.

Comment: Uups sorry, ja ich meinte @tofro. :) Aber danke für die Erklärung!